# Como mostrar el input radio seleccionado por un usuario al momento de imprimir pantalla

Tags: php, html, checkbox, entrada, radio

es la primera vez que solicito ayuda dado que estoy trabada en un código desde hace unos cuantos días, busqué tutoriales y ayudas por internet pero no pude resolverlos por eso acudo a molestarlos un ratito para ver si alguien me puede dar una mano.

Estoy realizando un formulario en html el cual luego por php me muestra los datos ingresados por el usuario, pero mi gran duda viene al utilizar los inputs de tipo radio o checkbox. Quiere mostrar en pantalla el dato que fue guardado imprimiendo el item seleccionado por el usuario pero que a la vez también me aparezcan las demás opciones seleccionadas. Hasta el momento lo que pude hacer es mostrar ese dato seleccionado pero duplicando la opción. A continuación coloco el código que estoy realizando fuera del proyecto para ver si entiendo la dinámica. Desde ya muchisimas gracias a la ayuda que puedan brindarme. Saludos!

```
    <form action="pruebaRB.php" name="formPruebaJs" method="post">

<tr>      
<td style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value="juan" id="nombreEmpleado"> Juan
  <input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value="carlos" id="nombreEmpleado"> Carlos <sup>1</sup> 
  <input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value="luis" id="nombreEmpleado"> Luis <sup>2</sup> 
</td>
```

```
</form>

<?php 


    require "conexion.php";

    $nombreEmpleado = $_POST["nombreEmpleado"];

    $sqlprueba = "INSERT INTO empleado( nombreEmpleado
                                        )
                                    VALUES(
                                           '".$nombreEmpleado."'
                                        )";

    $resultadoPrueba = mysqli_query($link,$sqlprueba)
                                        or die( mysqli_error($link));
$chequeo = mysqli_affected_rows($link);

mysqli_close($link);
```

?>

```
  <input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value=[$nombreEmpleado] checked> <?php echo $nombreEmpleado; ?>

  <input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value="juan" id="nombreEmpleado"> Juan
  <input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value="Carlos" id="nombreEmpleado"> Carlos 
  <input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value="Luis" id="nombreEmpleado" > Luis 
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tendrías que hacer es modificar tu formulario en PHP y utilizar la propiedad *checked* que tienen los *input radio*.

Es decir:

```
$juanIsChecked = $nombreEmpleado == 'juan' ? 'checked' : '';
<input type="radio" ... value="juan" $juanIsChecked />
```

Y así con cada uno de los campos.

Answer (score 1):

En el html cambia esto `name="nombreEmpleado[]"`, es decir, agrega los corchetes `[]` con esto haces que PHP acceda a los valores seleccionados como un array. Luego simplemente, si hay algún checkbox `nombreEmpleado` seleccionado lo metes en una variable `$empleado` que la recorres en un array para finalmente pintarla en un `echo`

Saludos

```
if (isset($_POST['nombreEmpleado'])) {
    $empleados = $_POST['nombreEmpleado'];
    echo 'empleados seleccionados: ';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($empleados); $i++) {
        echo $empleados[$i] . ' ';
    }
} else {
    echo 'no has marcado ninguna casilla';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría en este caso, es agregar una casilla mas a la tabla de base de datos llamada `select` con un valor booleano.

Tu tabla seria asi:

```
Tabla empleados
Id      | Nombre Emp. | Select
1       | Juan        | true
```

Y mediante un bucle generado con los checkbox o ratio, marcarlos con checked.
Y eso seria mas o menos asi:

```
<?php
require "conexion.php";
$sqlprueba = "SELECT * FROM empleados";
$resultadoPrueba = mysqli_query($link, $sqlprueba) or die( mysqli_error($link));
while ($row = mysqli_affected_rows($link)) {
    $check = $row["select"] === true ? " checked" : "";  
?>
<input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado[]" value="<?php echo $row["nombreEmpleado"]; ?>"<?php echo $check; ?>> <?php echo $row["nombreEmpleado"]; ?>
<?php
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Obviamente eso seria despues de haber insertado los datos, el codigo que muestro es solo para mostrar un listado de los empleaods que ya estan registrados en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos! Voy a ir chequeando cada idea que ustedes me dieron también pero ayer pude resolverlo de esta manera, se los mando por si alguien cae en la misma pregunta que yo y necesita una solución quizás le ayude. Saludos!

```
<input type="radio" name="nombreEmpleado" value="juan" <?php echo ($nombreEmpleado=='juan')?> checked>juan
```

(y así con cada input)

Answer (score -1):

Esta fue la solución que encontré:

```
<input type="radio" 
       id="t-option" 
       name="selector"  
       value="Envio Express ( 1 - 2 dias )" 
       <?php 
         if($temporal["envio"]=='Envio Express ( 1 - 2 dias )'){
           echo "checked";
         }
       ?>
       >
```